# Query using bigint attribute return empty for certain values

Tags: datomic

I created a minimal entity with one attribute of bigint type, my problem is that the query fail for certain values; this is the  schema:

```
  [{:db/ident :home/area,
    :db/valueType :db.type/bigint,
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one,
    :db/doc "the doc",
    :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db,
    :db/id #db/id[:db.part/db -1000013]}]
```

I inserted a sample value:

```
(d/transact (d/connect uri2)
            [{
              :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
              :home/area 123456789000000N}
             ])
```

And confirmed that It was created by using the datomic console. It happens that the following query doesn’t return the entity previously inserted, as expected:

```
(d/q '[
       :find ?e
       :in $ ?h
       :where
       [?e :home/area ?h]]
     (d/db (d/connect uri2))
     123456789000000N
     )
;;--- #{}
```

Maybe I’m missing something in the way the value  is expressed. Another test using a different value like 100N for the attribute :home/area returns the correct answer:

```
(d/transact (d/connect uri2)
            [{
              :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
              :home/area 100N}
             ])

(d/q '[
       :find ?e
       :in $ ?h
       :where
       [?e :home/area ?h]]
     (d/db (d/connect uri2))
     100N
     )
;;-- #{[17592186045451]}
```

Also works fine with the value 111111111111111111111111111111111111N which is confusing to me.

> Datomic version: "0.9.5390" java version "1.8.0_05" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode) MySQL as Storage service

Thanks in advance for any any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

To Clojure users, the name `:db.type/bigint` can be misleading, since [it actually maps](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html) to `java.math.BigInteger`, not `clojure.lang.BigInt`.

I reproduced the same steps and I can't tell you why the Datalog query fails on `123456789000000N` but not `100N` and `111111111111111111111111111111111111N`. It seems however that the following always works:

```
(d/q '[
       :find ?e
       :in $ ?h
       :where
       [?e :home/area ?h]]
     (d/db (d/connect uri2))
     (.toBigInteger 100N)
     )
```

Comment: I changed the three examples following your suggestion ( use .toBigInteger method) and all of them works fine. Definitively it is related with the value during the query binding. I'll continue searching for the reasons behind that, but I can use this workaround for my project. Thanks Valentin

Answer (score 1):

I ran your example and got different results (it worked in all cases). I am not sure why, but maybe adding my example will help.  The only changes I made were to use `uri` instead of `uri2`, I slurped the schema, and I performed a `(def conn (d/connect uri))` and a `(d/create-database uri)`.  I assume you performed similar steps, which is why I don't know why my example worked:

```
 Clojure 1.8.0
 user=> (use '[datomic.api :only [q db] :as d])
 nil
 user=> (use 'clojure.pprint)
 nil
 user=> (def uri "datomic:mem://bigint")
 #'user/uri
 user=> (d/create-database uri)
 true
 user=> (def conn (d/connect uri))
 #'user/conn
 user=> (def schema-tx (read-string (slurp "path/to/the/schema.edn")))
 #'user/schema-tx
 user=> @(d/transact conn schema-tx)
 {:db-before datomic.db.Db@b8774875, 
        :db-after datomic.db.Db@321a2712, 
 :tx-data [#datom[13194139534312 50 #inst "2016-08-14T18:53:23.158-00:00" 13194139534312 true] 
       #datom[63 10 :home/area 13194139534312 true] #datom[63 40 60 13194139534312 true] 
       #datom[63 41 35 13194139534312 true] #datom[63 62 "the doc" 13194139534312 true] 
       #datom[0 13 63 13194139534312 true]], 
 :tempids {-9223367638809264717 63}}

(d/transact (d/connect uri)
   [{
:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
:home/area 123456789000000N}
    ])
 #object[datomic.promise$settable_future$reify__6480 0x5634d0f4 
    {:status :ready, :val {:db-before datomic.db.Db@321a2712, 
                                      :db-after datomic.db.Db@f6ef3cd8, 
                           :tx-data [#datom[13194139534313 50 #inst "2016-08-14T18:53:34.325-00:00" 13194139534313 true] 
                                     #datom[17592186045418 63 123456789000000N 13194139534313 true]], 
                           :tempids {-9223350046623220288 17592186045418}}}]
 (d/q '[
   :find ?e
   :in $ ?h
   :where
   [?e :home/area ?h]]
   (d/db (d/connect uri))
   123456789000000N
   )
 #{[17592186045418]}

 (d/transact (d/connect uri)
   [{
:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
:home/area 100N}
    ])
 #object[datomic.promise$settable_future$reify__6480 0x3b27b497 
    {:status :ready, :val {:db-before datomic.db.Db@f6ef3cd8, 
                                      :db-after datomic.db.Db@2385c058, 
                           :tx-data [#datom[13194139534315 50 #inst "2016-08-14T18:54:13.347-00:00" 13194139534315 true] 
                                     #datom[17592186045420 63 100N 13194139534315 true]], 
                           :tempids {-9223350046623220289 17592186045420}}}]
 (d/q '[
   :find ?e
   :in $ ?h
   :where
   [?e :home/area ?h]]
   (d/db (d/connect uri))
   100N
   )
 #{[17592186045420]}
  user=>
```

Can you run `(first schema-tx)` on the REPL line to confirm your schema transacted?  I noticed you were using the console and I am wondering if `/bigint` did not get defined or you were looking at the first `uri` (since I noticed you had a 2, I am assuming you have multiple examples).

Comment: Jaret, I ran all the steps you showed in your code, and everything works as expected, so maybe there is something related to the storage (you used mem and I use MySQL). BTW the result of (first schema-tx) is:

{:db/ident :home/area, :db/valueType :db.type/bigint, :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one, :db/doc "the doc", :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db, :db/id #db/id[:db.part/db -1000013]}

I also confirmed that the schema was successfully created.

Comment: @CésarCastillo Valentin Waeselynck is right. Although clojure.lang.BigInt and java.math.BigInteger are largely interchangeable in practice, it does look like Datomic query relies upon one of the ways in which they are different. If you pass a java BigInteger to your query instead, it ought to work. The memory version works because it is using the same object instance.